# How to control height and font size of a block anchor tag

Tags: html, css, anchor

I'm trying to set different height and font-size of an anchor tag that is displayed as block element
however the font-size ends up overriding the height of the element each time.. any idea?

```
div{
    background: #916a31;
    height: 2.3em;
}

ul, li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    float: left;
    background: orange;
    height: 2em;
    width: 100%;

}
li {

}

li a{
    display: block;
    font-size: .5em;
    font-family: tahoma;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    background: red;
    padding: 0 10px;
}


<div class="div cf">
    <ul class="unlist">

            <li><a href="#" class="anchor">one </a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="anchor">two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="anchor">three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="anchor">four</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please re-phrase your question? It's very unclear.

Comment: Yes, very unclear. I'm assuming the issue is to do with all the fixed heights you have (bad idea). Try changing them to min-heights.

Comment: Keep in mind that [`em` units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#em-unit) are relative to font size. So, given your code, changing the `font-size` of your `<a>` will also change its `height`.

Comment: OMG, how could I miss that! thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

higher layer element you want a different size can be added a ' !important ' in its css height. Try it . ' !important ' mean that element should use its height value at the top priority